# Using jsonpath in api.ai in case we have already our json file to query in?

Tags: python, json, webhooks, jsonpath, dialogflow-es

```
import json


def makeWebhookResult(req):
    if req.get("result").get("action") != "Phdapp":
        return {}
    result = req.get("result")
    parameters = result.get("parameters")

    Progr = parameters.get("PhDsubjects")
    time = parameters.get("PhdTime")
    Levp = parameters.get("PhDDegLevp")

    with open('Sheet1.json') as f:
        data = f.read()
        jsondata = json.loads(data)




    match = jsonpath.jsonpath(jsondata,
                              '$.features[[?(@.ProgramName == Progr && @.Level == Levp && @.StartDate == time)]].UniversityName')


    speech = "This is the universities you were looking for " + match
```

[This is the part of my python code which have errors i can't figure it out, I have an intent with action which is "Phdapp" with three parameters that i need to use their values in my jsonpath querying from "sheet1.json" file in the same repository on GitHub in json format. But i can't get data from my intent neither accessing my son file for querying...is it because api.ai is not compatible with jsonpath or it is the problem of my code! or if there is a best to use which easier it can be my pleasure to know it. Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlvm4.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll get better results here if you format your question more carefully than you did, and if you show some code examples. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Also, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.